# use std with Vectorxd from eigen library

Tags: c++, std, eigen

Its possible use std::swap function to elements of VectorXd in eigen lib like this? is it correct?

```
   Eigen::VectorXd   val2;

   std::swap(val2[i], val2[k + i]);
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: thats the point i dont have any option to try this.:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{

  VectorXd e_vec(5);
  e_vec << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
  std::swap(e_vec[0], e_vec[2]);

  std::cout << e_vec << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
3
2
1
4
5
```